# How to loop through dataset

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to go through each row of a dataset and find the smallest distance formula for the select numbers in each row and put it in a `vector(acc)`.

I have done some research with other questions and this is the code that I got.

```
a=1
b=1
n=1

for(i in 1:nrow(satest_tDCS_01_split)){

    while(a==b){
        d=100000
        t=1
        e=9
        f=10

        while(t< 5){
            c<-sqrt(((satest_tDCS_01_split[n,22]-satest_tDCS_01_split[n,e])^2)
            +((satest_tDCS_01_split[n,23]-satest_tDCS_01_split[n,f])^2))

            if(c<d){
                d<-c
            }

            e=as.numeric(e)+3
            f=as.numeric(f)+3
            t=t+1
        }

        acc<-c()
        acc<-append(acc,d)
        n=as.numeric(n)+1
        a<-satest_tDCS_01[n,4]
        b<-satest_tDCS_01[n+1,4]
    }
}
```

What I am expecting is a `vector(acc)` of numbers `d` but I don't even get `acc` when I run it. What I think is wrong is that the for loop is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script `acc <- c()` inside the loop will reset the `acc` in every iteration. Move it outside the loop may help.